# How to put an image in html that's in sub folders

Tags: css

I've been trying to figure out how to put an image in html and it's not working. I saved the image to jpg and its in a couple folders from the computer. It's in a drop off folder and another CS folder then I have to click on my teachers folder then the class then my name and I click on another folder called project then finally reach the folder where I have my index.html saved and a separate folder in that project folder called images. I've tried everything and still it won't appear for me

Comment: Care to share the code you have?

Comment: <img src="images/pictureofme.jpg">

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the path to the image relatively to where your HTML file is.

So say your index.html file lies at `C:/someFolder/anotherFolder/index.html` and your image lies at `C:/someFolder/anotherFolder/images/myImage.jpg` then you will have to add the following code to your index.html: `<img src="images/myImage.jpg alt="My alternative text">`

Answer (score 0):

put attribute on your tag `<img>`,

```
relative "src=../folder" 
absolut "src=http://mycompany.com/css/myimg.jpg"
```

example:

```
<img src="http://company.com/css/img.png"></img>
<img src="C:\user\img.png"> for windows
<img src="../css/img.png"> same netbeans editor
```